# Combine OF and of

Tags: isabelle

I recently began using more OF as a way to discharge assumptions of a lemma with local theorems. I also use of as a way to give concrete values to the variables of a theorem. For instance in the following theorem:

```
periodic ?f ?k ⟹
0 < ?k ⟹
0 < ?d ⟹ sum ?f {0..?k - 1} = sum ?f {?d..?d + ?k - 1}
```

I would like to discharge `periodic ?f ?k` and `0 < ?k` with OF and then apply of to instantiate `?d = 1`. The current way I do this is by a two step process:

```
note lem = my_lemma[OF ...]
using lem[of ...]
```

I was wondering if there is a more elegant syntax for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just write `my_lemma[OF …, of …, OF …, of …]` etc. This works for *any* attribute, e.g. `my_lemma[OF …, where x = …, simplified, symmetric]`

Comment: is there a list of these attributes somewhere?

Comment: Well, there's `print_attributes` (probably not very helpful) and the Isabelle/Isar reference manual. But the important ones are `of`, `OF`, `where`, `symmetric`, `abs_def`. Occasionally also `simplified`, `case_names`, `consumes`. And fact collections like `simp`, `intro`, `dest`, `elim`, `continuous_intros`, `derivative_intros`.